# Measurable Solutions of Cauchy Functional equation are linear : Sierpinski's proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The proof is based on this lemma :

Lemma : Given $ P, T \subset R $ be sets of positive measure. Then there exist $ p \in P $ and $ t \in T $ such that $ p-t\in Q $

I could prove the above lemma  by assuming $ P, T $ are measurable sets which is enough to show measurable solutions of Cauchy functional equation are linear. Is the assumption of measurability necessary in the above lemma ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need not just the measurability assumption, but the positivity of the measure. For example, take $T = \Bbb{Q}$ and $P = \Bbb{Q} + \sqrt{2}$. These are both countable, hence measurable, and have measure $0$. However, if $p \in P$, then $p = q + \sqrt{2}$ for some $q \in \Bbb{Q}$, so for any $t \in T = \Bbb{Q}$, we have
$$p - t = \sqrt{2} + (p - t).$$
If this were equal to some $r \in \Bbb{Q}$, then
$$\sqrt{2} = r - p + t \in \Bbb{Q},$$
which we all know is false.

Comment: Is the lemma true by assuming positive measure without measurability ?

Comment: @ibnAbu What does it mean for a non-measurable set to have positive measure?